# Is there a way to display custom error pages in IIS for only parts of a website?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap, iis-7.5, custom-errors

I have a website that exposes regular web pages as well as a WCF webservice.
Ideally the webpages should display custom error pages for status 500 (using httpError in web.config) while the web service throws soap errors.

Unfortunately the custom error pages for status 500 will also hide the soap errors with a custom error page.

Is there a way to enable custom error pages in IIS 7.5 for only parts of a website? (I can't put the web service in a separate site, it depends on runtime objects in the web pages.)

Comment: IIS settings can be set at file level by using location tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your webservice files are stored in a directory separate from the rest of the site, you can just put a new `web.config` file in that directory and set a `<httpErrors>` node there. This will override the settings in the root web.config

If you don't have a clean separation between your normal URIs and your webservice URIs, you can use the location node in your root web.config e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="service/foo.aspx">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpErrors>
                <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
            </httpErrors>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

You can have as many of these location nodes as you need.

Comment: Thanks. This answer solved my problem.
I choose the use the location-element (because I wanted to maintain only a single web.config) and it worked as described, overriding the error-handling for that location only.